# ClipToBounds and HorizontalAlignment on StackPanel are not working on resizing

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have problem with `ClipToBounds` in `StackPanel`. If user resizes the `ListBox` by making window smaller the `ListBoxItems` still keep the width.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1"  >
 <Grid>
 ...
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
 ...
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Textblock...
        <Textblock...
```

When I refresh content of the listbox everything fits nicely but when grid that holds `ListBox` is resized (made smaller) those stackpanels do not respect `HorizontalAlignment` and `ClipToBounds` and keep `ListBoxItems` wider than `ListBox`.

Is there a way around it?

Comment: You can listen for a `SizeChanged` event to fire off `UpdateLayout` but it can have an adverse effect on performance if over used. However your use of ClipToBounds may not be necessary if you can organize things to not need it.

Comment: Remove the `StackPanel` and use proper containers. A `StackPanel` will not stretch it's children in the direction of the stacking. This means, if the `StackPanel` has `Orientation="Horizontal"`, it will have infinite horizontal space and it's children will not "know" what's the maximum / desired width. You need a `Grid`, `DockPanel` or some other container. And BTW this is a Layout concern which has nothing to do with ClipToBounds,  which is more of a render concept.

Comment: @HighCore I have tried replacing second StackPanel with Grid and DockPanel but it was the same. It does work if I listen to SizeChanged and set width to parent ActualWidth but I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: @MilS no events / procedural code are required for Layout concerns in WPF. Some part of your XAML is wrong. Post the full XAML and a screenshot of what you get versus what you expect.

Comment: As HighCore says, drop the use of `StackPanel` - they're really not great for most non-trivial layout. Post your full xaml. From your description I'd guess that one of the children somewhere is defining a `Width` or `MinWidth`. A `Grid` will automatically resize to fit its parent space, and if the children of the grid have `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` then they will resize to fit the Grid cell they are in. No code needed, beyond xaml layout.